# Можно ли из одного репозитория github сделать два

Tags: git, github

Всех приветствую!

У меня есть репозиторий пока что с одной веткой (master), на которой находится пользовательская программа. Так вот, могу ли я создать вторую ветку (admin), удалить на ней файлы из ветки (master) и закинуть программу для админа.

Comment: можно, конечно. только зачем? ведь теряется смысл использования программы git — системы управления изменениями исходных текстов. заведите лучше новый репозиторий.

Comment: так программа по сути одна, только первая для пользователя, а вторая следить за всеми данными пользователя

Comment: программа git ничего не знает про то, что за исходные тексты вы в ней храните. зачем они нужны — это уже ваше дело, а не этой программы. она лишь помогает в управлении изменениями этих исходных текстов. если у вас есть два разных набора исходных текстов — логичнее хранить их в разных репозиториях. иначе теряется смысл в использовании этой программы (git).

Comment: В данном случае лучше хранить все вместе (и пользовательску и админскую). А вот когда генерируется инсталляция, вот тут уже разделять. То есть, "билд скрипты" должны разделять код. Иначе в репозитории появися куча веток, в которых будут хранится разные версии одной с программ и будет очень тяжело это все соединить вместе.

Comment: Понял, всем огромное спасибо!